# How to make a contenteditable div produce smart quotes instead of dumb quotes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I write stuff in Google Docs I noticed I get the “” (smart quotes). But when I create contenteditable divs on my own I get "" (dumb quotes).

How to make my contenteditable divs produce smart quotes instead of dumb quotes?

Comment: Stack Exchange produces the curvy ones in titles...

Comment: OK, I made it clear now. I meant the content area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'content area'... What 'content area'??

On SO, the `textarea` where you type an answer?
Or what you see when you post the answer?
Or just any div with property 'contenteditable'?

In all cases I'd be pretty <not feeling so nice> if *good* quotes (that I type/copy/paste) automatically get replaced by those *pesky* curly/smart quotes <sup>(my coder-tainted opinion)</sup>. So (I'd hate to be proven wrong): Google Docs probably `replace`s them for you (just like Word (by default), from which you could also get 'infected' by them by opening/importing Word-files or simply copying text from Word to Google Docs) and I'm betting one can turn that off in Google Docs.

Thank <enter deity here>: (in Google Docs) click on "Preferences" under the "Tools" menu in an open document, then uncheck "Use Smart Quotes"

So, IF you'd want that 'feature' in your project:

- Be sure one can turn it off and that setting is easy to find
- **Replace** the straight ones with corresponding ones

  - before the content enters your DB
  - when outputting the stored content (from your DB) them to your 'content-area'

One could/should use javascript on the client-side (and preferably a preview (like on SO) as to not to interfere with the user typing and the cursor jumping around for which you'd search a jumbo-jet-weight x-browser library etc etc etc follow-up problems) to show the user how his input is going to look.

**EDIT:** I highlighted the word ***'replace'*** once more (in light of the edited question).